# each() does not work on IE8, and gave me a "apply array or arguments object expected". how to solve it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap v2.3.1 on my website, but when I test it on IE8, I got an error

> "apply array or arguments object expected".

here is bootstrap part:

```
 enter : function (t)
        {
            var n = e.fn[this.type].defaults, r = {}, i;
            this._options && e.each(this._options, function (e, t)
            {
                n[e] != t && (r[e] = t);
            }, this), i = e(t.currentTarget)[this.type](r).data(this.type);
            if (!i.options.delay || !i.options.delay.show) {
                return i.show();
            }
            clearTimeout(this.timeout), i.hoverState = "in", this.timeout = setTimeout(function ()
            {
                i.hoverState == "in" && i.show()
            },
            i.options.delay.show)
        }
```

and jQuery part:

```
each: function( obj, callback, args ) {
        var name,
            i = 0,
            length = obj.length,
            isObj = length === undefined || jQuery.isFunction( obj );

        if ( args ) {
            if ( isObj ) {
                for ( name in obj ) {
                    if ( callback.apply( obj[ name ], args ) === false ) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for ( ; i < length; ) {
                    if ( callback.apply( obj[ i++ ], args ) === false ) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

when I ran to `callback.apply( obj[ name ], args )`, I got that error,

the main problem is

```
e.each(this._options, function (e, t)
            {
                n[e] != t && (r[e] = t);
            }, this);
```

does not work on IE8 and "apply array or arguments object expected" happend.

could any help me to solve that ?

Comment: Mmmmm. This is a bit unclear. Is this _your_ code or are you showing jquery and bootstrap javascript (which most likely are ok). Please elaborate What are you trying to do when the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by makeArray(), like this :

```
each: function( obj, callback, args ) {
        var name,
            i = 0,
            length = obj.length,
            isObj = length === undefined || jQuery.isFunction( obj );

        if ( args ) {
            if ( isObj ) {
                for ( name in obj ) {
                    if ( $.browser.msie && '8.0' == $.browser.version ) {
                        args = $.makeArray(args);
                    }

                    if ( callback.apply( obj[ name ], args ) === false ) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for ( ; i < length; ) {
                    if ( callback.apply( obj[ i++ ], args ) === false ) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

but callback.apply( obj[ name ], $.makeArray(args)) also works on Chrome, but I am not sure
that's okay, if the browser is IE8, then I do this.